# Convert character to factor with guaranteed code order

Tags: r, numbers, categorical-data, deterministic

I am dealing with data that includes binary variables, which arrive coded as characters. At one point, I convert them to factors.

At a different point, I have to convert them to numbers, and deal with the numbers' value. Basically, I am doing something very similar to the rescaling in the `arm` package, and I need two numerical values for the two categories, so I can calculate a mean. I don't care that much which two values, but once they have been used, I need the same values for each batch of data.

For example, if I have the variable "ikt" coded as "y" and "n", and I run my code once, I may do

```
ikt <- c("y", "n", "n", "n") 
ikt.factor <- as.factor(ikt) 
ikt.num <- as.numeric(ikt.factor)
```

and now that I ran it, I got `ikt.num` to contain `2,1,1,1`.

The question is, how can I get R to always create the same conversion, and never `1,2,2,2`? I need this to happen independently of the dataset and the environment, as long as I can guarantee that the "ikt" column will always arrive coded as "y" and "n".

I don't want to have to hardcode the correspondence of variable levels to numbers, since this code has to work generically for different binary variables, which can arrive with different character codes.

Comment: The default ordering is alphabetical. Or you can specify the order of the levels using `ikt.factor <- factor(ikt, levels = c("y", "n"))`. This is safest because it's robust even if `ikt` is already a factor with non-alphabetical levels.

Comment: The statements "I need two numerical values for the two categories, so I can calculate a mean" and "I don't care that much which two values" seem contradictory to me.  The mean will depend both on the values chosen and on the relative proportions with which the two values appear.  So if you don't care which values you use, you don't care what the value of the mean is.  Or put another way, if you let me choose arbitrary values, I can give you whatever mean I want.  Far better, IMHO, to always use 0 and 1 so that the mean can be interpreted as a proportion.